# convert whole byte[] into uint

Tags: c#, .net

I have byte[] srno in my code

```
byte[] srno = new byte[6];

srno[0] = 0xff;
srno[1] = 0x0f;
srno[2] = 0x24;
srno[3] = 0x12;
srno[4] = 0x16;
srno[5] = 0x0a;
```

now I want this value in uint like

```
uint a = 0xff0f2412160a;
```

How to convert it?

Comment: A `uint` is 4 bytes, but you've got 6 bytes there. In any case, do you know of the `BitConverter` class?

Comment: Just do the math: `srno[0] * 0x10000000000 + srn0[1] * 0x100000000 ...`. Or whatever.

Comment: @Ani: ok no problem tell me for ulong ?
BitConverter class need index I dont want for perticular index I want to convert whole array

Comment: @Kevan: If you would read the documentation, you would notice that the index tells the bit converter where it should *start* the conversion.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As @animaonline suggested, you should use `BitConverter` to convert byte array to *uint* or *ulong. Thus you have 6 bytes, *uint* is too small for you. You should convert to ulong*. But converter requires eight bytes, so create new array with required number of bytes:

```
byte[] value = new byte[8];
Array.Reverse(srno); // otherwise you will have a1612240fff result
Array.Copy(srno, value, 6);
ulong result = BitConverter.ToUInt64(value, 0);
Console.WriteLine("{0:x}", result); // ff0f2412160a
```

Answer (score 2):

In System namespace you will find the `BitConverter` library class. You want the static `ToUInt64()` function as follows:

```
var a = BitConverter.ToUInt64(srno, 0);
```

You will need to adjust the size of your array to `[8]`

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.touint64.aspx)

Comment: u need to reverse the array first!

Answer (score 0):

Everyone seems to be ignoring the byte-order encoding of his expected output. The `BitConverter` class uses a fixed encoding (usually Little-Endian, IIRC). The output in the example is assumed to be Big-Endian. In a perfect world you'd just do the math yourself, but it's simpler to use `Array.Reverse` then use the inbuilt `BitConverter` class.

There are probably going to be a heap of answers before I get to post this so here's a really quick piece of unsafe code:

```
public static unsafe ulong ToULong(byte[] values)
{
    byte* buffer = stackalloc byte[8];
    if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
        Array.Reverse(values);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(values, 0, (IntPtr)buffer, values.Length);
    return *(ulong*)buffer;
}
```